# wxApp get stuck when closing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, wxwidgets

I've added new dialogs and pieces to my wxApp, but now when I close the main frame, the main frame get deleted but it never get to the OnExit function, and is stuck.

When I try to "break all", it get in this function call:

`wxIdleWakeUpModule::MsgHookProc`

in:

`return CallNextHookEx(ms_hMsgHookProc, nCode, wParam, lParam);`

Do you have any advice on how to fix that ?

Comment: Do you set up any message hooks in your app and not clean up correcty?

Comment: Do you do any wxIdleEvent handling anywhere?  Stick a breakpoint in there to see if it is called when it doesn't exit.  Perhaps it is causing more messages to be posted to the event queue, which then causes it to idle again and post more events and so n.

Comment: Pete, I don't know what a message hook is, so maybe I don't have any. Also the only event I generate myself are `wxCommandEvent`, I don't know if it is a wxIdleEvent as well

Comment: @jules see my answer: if you call destroy on dialog close the dialog will be removed from the message queue and the application will close when no windows/dialogs are present.

Comment: @jules can you post a minimal sample or a pseudocode of what is happening in your application? (how is the frame created and how are the dialogs created)

Comment: @lulian it's going to be hard for me to post code, there's too much of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I've tested one by one all the pieces of code I've added to my previously working program, I've realized that one of the `wxDialog` I was creating had no parent, but this was not intended.

So because of that it would not close because one of the main window was still alive (even though it was not shown)

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use Destroy when dialog is closed. This [page](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxdialog.html) shows how to do that when creating an object on heap:

```
void AskUser()
{
    MyAskDialog *dlg = new MyAskDialog(...);
    if ( dlg->ShowModal() == wxID_OK )
        ...
    //else: dialog was cancelled or some another button pressed

    dlg->Destroy();
}
```

When the dialog is created on the stack you shouldn't do anything special.

Comment: I am not sure this is going to help, since in my case the main frame will destroy by it self when it is closed, and destroy all it's children as well.

Comment: @jules Have you tried? Do this also on the frame. When closing the frame call `Destroy`

Comment: @jules see also http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowdestroy and http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxcloseevent.html#wxcloseevent

Comment: @lulian I've tried destroying my main window, and the Frame/Dialog I've created. It did not work. I've also tried to delete at "close" time the controller of the frame (in case it was generating event). It did not work.

Comment: @jules Handle the close event of the frame and use `Destroy` there. Also on the close event of the dialogs created on the head call also `Destroy`. This should remove all components from the event loop